# Import CSV file data into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I am inserting record from CSV file to MySQL table; if any record already exists update that record and insert other records and if there is no match of the record insert all records.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
    if (!$connect) {
     die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $cid =mysql_select_db('bizin490_devcredit',$connect);
    define('CSV_PATH', '/home/ubc/Documents/');
    $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "test.csv";
    $csvfile  = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
    $theData  = fgets($csvfile);
    $i = 0;
    while (!feof($csvfile)) {

     $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
     $csv_array  = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
     $insert_csv = array();
     $insert_csv['name']  = $csv_array[0];
     $insert_csv['email'] = $csv_array[1];

     $query = mysql_query("select name from test where name='" . $insert_csv['name'] . "'");
     $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

     if ($count == 0) {
      $query = "INSERT INTO test(name,email)VALUES('" . $insert_csv['name'] . "','" .  $insert_csv['email'] . "')";

      $n = mysql_query($query, $connect);

      } else {

        $sql = "update test set email='".$insert_csv['email']."'";
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($sql);
        $qu  = mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);
      }
     $i++;
     //die;
   }
   fclose($csvfile);
   echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
   mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: What is your issue???

Comment: My Issues is , when it update records, it makes updated fileds balnk in database

Comment: $insert_csv['email'] may be null

Comment: Yes but how i am passing there value you can see in my code.

Comment: Use MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

Comment: @MarkBaker He wants to check before insert, If matches then update.

Comment: And LOAD DATA INFILE provides that functionality via `[REPLACE | IGNORE]`

Comment: can you please make a query using LOAD DATA INFILE in the above mentioned code, here i am trying but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/ubc/Documents/test.csv'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE `test`
(name, email)
```