# How to insert and update table from exact column of csv file upload in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a csv file like this

```
id,question,ans_number, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4...
```

I want to insert and update `my_table`, `ans_table` from that uploaded csv file. If the data not exists in `my_table`, I just want to insert only id and question from csv file into `my_table` as a new record and if exists, I want to update only question on existing data.

In `my_table`, I have column like this

```
id,question,status,question_group,department
```

id is auto_increment and primary key.

For `ans_table`, I want to insert and update from the rest of csv file data such as ans_number,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4... .Its the same procedure with `my_table`.

In `ans_table`, columns are

```
id,name,my_table_id
```

`my_table_id` is the id from `my_table`.

I try a lot to solve this problem. But I can't because I am newbie in php. I very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719280/import-csv-file-data-into-mysql-table).This help for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your mysql connection
...
if (($handle = fopen($csv_filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table(id, question) VALUES({$row[0]}, {$row[1]}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE question = VALUES(question);");
        // assuming that ans_table.id field is auto-increment and primary key
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ans_table(my_table_id, ans_number, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4) VALUES({$row[0]}, {$row[2]},{$row[3]}, {$row[4]}, {$row[5]}, {$row[6]});");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: I want to also update data from ans_table. How to make it? Thank you for your answer **Roman Perekhrest**.

Comment: If you want to provide "one-to-one" relation between My_table and Ans_table(only one record from 'ans_table' relates to distinct record from 'my_table') then assign ans_table.'my_table_id' field as unique key and append such complement "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ans1 = VALUES(ans1) AND ans2 = VALUES(ans2) ... and so on;" to ans_table insert query